# Closing Go channel does not trigger receiver in go routine

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

```
package main

import "fmt"

func routine(doneCh <-chan struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-doneCh:
            fmt.Println("Routine done") // This never prints
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    doneCh := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    go routine(doneCh)

    close(doneCh)
}
```

However, if I add `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` the output does print. What would be the idiomatic way to have the routine receive from `doneCh` on close before the program exits?

Comment: You're likely exiting the main function before the goroutine has a chance to receive any messages. What does the close function look like?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 close is a built in function that closes channels.

Comment: Ah, thanks (still learning the language). This indeed appears to be a matter of main exiting before the goroutine prints.

Comment: @OneOfOne I tried searching for a similar question but I quite couldn't find one that has the answer I am looking for. Can you provide a link to the existing question? Edit: I see the link.

Comment: @cleung2010 no problem, welcome to Go!